# Problem Burning a DVD with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, dvd, burning

When I burn my files to a DVD using the Windows 7 drag and drop I can't actually see my files.  Windows doesn't seem to finsih the DVD, even though I have followed the steps to do this.

When I put the dvd in my XP machine it can see the files - so I know they are definatley being written correctly.

Why can't I seem to finish the DVD correctly?  Is there some view I have set to see files already written?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to view the files on a Mac? Macs seem to need a CD/DVD to be "fixated" in order to view the files, but that means that you cannot write anything else to the disk. Windows doesn't fixate the disk, so that you can write more stuff to it later. You can use the free [InfraRecorder](http://infrarecorder.org/) to "fixate" the disk.